# Why my shell script doesn't work in Alfred 2 Workflow

Tags: shell, workflow

I wrote a script like this,

```
#!/bin/sh
HEXO=/Users/cinvro/nvm/v0.10.15/bin/hexo
cd ~/Work/hexo/cinvro.com/
$HEXO generate
```

it works when I execute it in my terminal,but it doesn't work when I put it in a Alfred2 Workflow.

hexo here is a node.js program.

Comment: apple mac specific ? move to http://apple.stackexchange.com/  ?

Answer (score 1):

It might be `~` problem, just replace with the absolute path:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
HEXO=/Users/cinvro/nvm/v0.10.15/bin/hexo
cd /Users/cinvro/Work/hexo/cinvro.com/
$HEXO generate
```